# Hard to explain question. Downconvert/limit string to a certain charset without stripping

Tags: string, character-encoding, char, alphanumeric

I've encountered this problem a few times, and now I finally decided to ask, hoping someone knows what I'm talking about.

What I wish to do is this form of char convertion:

```
ÆØÅ => AOA
ÉÈÊ => EEE
üÿï => uyi
```

So far the closest I've come to a search criteria I can type into google as this:

- Something similar to base64/URLEncode
- A sound algorithm such as [Metaphone](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.metaphone.php) or [Soundex](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.soundex.php)

This did not work as expected. There seemed to be no correlation between `ÉÈÊ` and `EEE` any different from that and `ÆØÅ`. So, held up against E, all six chars would've been converted to E, which wasn't the accuracy I was looking for.

- Convertion from the origin encoding (e.g. ASCII) to a charset/encoding consiting of only alphanumerics

I'm not very confident about this approach as the encoding would have to be able to recognize, say `E`, as an ancestor/nearest (alphanumeric) neighbour of `È`.

I feel like I'm saying a lot of words which are around the ballpark.

Does anyone understand what I'm trying to achieve, or know what this "method" I'm looking for is called?

Any ideas/thoughts are very much appreciates (and I do mean **any**),

- Mik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you'd have to consider a database of Unicode codepoints, mapping them to their nearest US-ASCII equivalent (where possible).  I imagine it would be a relatively sparse map, since most Unicode codepoints don't have a US-ASCII equivalent.

Hopefully this answer has some key words in that help you look for what you want.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid this, which gives somewhat of a blacklist vs. whitelist problem. If mapping is the only option, I hope, somewhere, there'll be an array of UTF8 -> US ASCII. Thank you for your answer.